# Я понимаю, что значит синхронизация по методу, но не пойму что такое синхронизация по объекту

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация, synchronized

Объясните мне, в чем разница между синхронизацией по методу и по объекту.
Для вашего правильного понимания того, как я реально это понимаю, привожу свое объяснение синхронизации по методу:

```java
public synchronized void inty(){
   i++;
}
```

В данном случае потоки выстраиваются в очередь перед методом, так как он промаркирован ключевым словом synchronized. То есть в данном случае, слово `synchronized` обозначает некую защелку, которую закрывает и открывает каждый входящий поток.
Но как понять запись типа

```java
public void inty(){
   synchronized (object){
     i++;
   }
}
```

Я не могу понять логику и не могу даже объяснить, как в данном случае работает код. Объясните на пальцах без применения высокоразвитых терминов.
Спасибо

Comment: В первом случае неявно происходит захват монитора того объекта, метод которого вызывается. Во втором случае поведение точно такое же, как при вызове синхронизированного метода, но захватывается монитор объекта, на который указывает переменная `object`.

Comment: Ключевое слово synchronized следует использовать в особых случаях, злоупотребление этим словом может вызвать чрезмерные блокировки работы программы вплоть до полного зависания.

Answer (score 3):

"Синхронизация по объекту" означает, что к объекту, являющемуся разделяемым ресурсом (второй случай), будет иметь доступ только один поток одновременно.

У каждого объекта в Java существует атрибут, обеспечивающий контроль за доступом к данному объекту. Он называется монитор (он же мьютекс).
Работает он так: если поток1 использует ресурс (объект) и захватил его монитор (с помощью synchronized), то поток2, желающий использовать тот же ресурс (объект), должен подождать освобождения монитора, захватить его и только потом начать использовать ресурс.

https://github.com/enhorse/java-interview/blob/master/concurrency.md